# Can you add a Mastodon profile to your Stack Overflow profile whilst keeping your website link?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, twitter

I would like to verify my Stack Overflow profile from my Mastodon profile.
I can achieve this by replacing my website URL with my Mastodon URL, but this would mean that my website would not be directly linked to from my Stack Overflow profile.

Would it be possible to allow linking to a Mastodon profile, the same way you can link to your Twitter profile?

Comment: Already [asked and declined by staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383594/add-a-mastodon-link-in-addition-to-twitter)

Comment: A thoughtful suggestion about evolving social links on Stack Exchange sites https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391139

Answer (score 2):

#### Would it be possible to allow linking to a Mastodon profile?

You **can** do this.

Edit your profile "About me" and add the link there. This allowed my to verify my Mastodon profile.

Example:

> [image]

Comment: Afaik, mastodon requires `rel="me"` on the link to verify an account. This is not possible with the About Me section, because [SO does not allow setting `rel`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/779559). It is only possible if you put the mastodon url as your Website link.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl I added a link with no `rel=me` and it still worked.